# Getting a Geometric Mean/SD based on column value in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am wondering if it is possible to get the geometric mean of a set of values based upon the value of another column using `dplyr`, or if there is a better way.

I have something like this as a `data.frame`

```
Days.Stay | Svc
5         | Med
6         | Surg
...       | ...
```

I'd like to get a column and call it `Geo.Mean.Days.Stay` or something like that, where the value is derived as the geometric mean of `Days.Stay` grouped by `Svc`, so each `Svc` will have its own unique geometric mean - and I would like to extend this to the geometric standard deviation. So a `data.frame` result like so:

```
Days.Stay | Svc | Geo.Mean.Days.Stay | Geo.SD.Days.Stay
5         | Med | 6.78               | 2.7
6         | Surg| 5.4                | 2.1
```

Is `dplyr` a good package for this or should I use an alternate method?

Comment: `%>% summarise(g= geom_mean(x))` where you define the function however you see fit, maybe `geom_mean = function(x) prod(x)^(1/length(x))`..?

Comment: or `exp(mean(log(x)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
library("dplyr")
dd %>% group_by(svc) %>%
    summarise(Geo.Mean.Days.Stay=exp(mean(log(Days.Stay))),
              Geo.SD.Days.Stay=exp(sd(log(Days.Stay))))
```

If you were going to use the geometric mean and SD on a regular basis it would be a good idea to define some helper functions (`gmean <- function(x) exp(mean(log(x)))`) to improve readability ...