# How do we build a loop/ if statement that meets several conditions at once?

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

We have a large data set with 150 beer brands, sold in 85 stores, during 399 weeks. 
The brands are still divided into sub brands (f.ex.: brand = Budweiser, but sub brands still exist: Budweiser light/ Budweiser regular etc.)
We want to create a function that creates a new column that gives us the average price per brand if:
- the brand is the same,
- the week is the same and
- the store is the same.

So our goal is to get a column that displays 1 average price per brand per week per store (f.ex.: Budweiser in store 1 in week 1). We struggle to create this if statement/ loop, as we are fairly new to R.

So far we have tried to solve this step, by understanding how it would work without a loop. Therefore, we selected the specific store,  brand, and week and created a vector of ones. Like this we could create the vector mean_price which sums up all the prices per week per store of all the sub brands and then divides them by the number of sub brands (calculated by summing up the vector of ones).

```
try1 <- subset(beer, select = c("brand","week","store","price_ounce","logprice_ounce", "sales_ounce","logsales_ounce"))

try1$vector <- c(1)

store5 <- subset(try1, store==5 & week==224 & brand=="ariel")
mean_price <- (sum(store5$logprice_ounce)/(sum(store5$vector)))
View(mean_price)
``

So far this leads to only one mean price, but we would like to have a column that displays 1 mean price per brand & store & week.
In the end, we need this to perform a regression to estimate price elasticities per store.

We are looking forward to any kind of help as we are completely lost.
Thank you in advance!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dplyr library is great for this type of analysis. You can achieve your mean per store / brand / beer in dplyr using:

```
library(dplyr)

brand <- c("bud", "bud", "bud")
week <- c(1,1,1)
store <- c("A", "A", "A")
price_ounce <- c(2,3,2.2)

data <- data.frame(brand, week, store, price_ounce) %>%
  mutate(logprice_ounce = log(price_ounce))

answer <- data %>% 
  group_by(brand, week, store) %>%
  summarise(meanPrice = mean(price_ounce),
            geomMeanPrice = exp(mean(logprice_ounce)))
```

You may find this book useful:
[R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/)

Comment: Thank you very much! That works perfectly.
How do we calculate it if we need the geometric mean? geoMEAN and geometric.mean does not work

Comment: You can build up your logic in your summarise function call. So in your example by replacing summarise above with summarise(geomMeanPrice = exp(mean(log(logprice_ounce)))). Or if price has already been log transformed: summarise(geomMeanPrice = exp(mean(logprice_ounce))). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554556/getting-a-geometric-mean-sd-based-on-column-value-in-dplyr

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. We get this Error message:

Fehler in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `as_dictionary()` is defunct as of rlang 0.3.0.
Please use `as_data_pronoun()` instead.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include simple test data and the geometric mean.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need any loop to do what you want to do.
You can, for example, use the library data.table

```
library(data.table)    
beer[, Mean:=mean(price_ounce), by=list(brand,week,store)]
```

You could do it with another library called *dplyr*, but I encourage you to have a look at *data.table* which is faster when it comes to deal with big datasets.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you @Mez13
For our regression, we also need to include the sum of logsales_ounce

adding: + summarise(sumSales = sum(logsales_ounce)) does not work...

Comment: So you just want to add another column as you just dit, right? You need to follow the same logic, I  mean `beer[, Sum_log:=sum(logsales_ounce), by=list(brand,week,store)]`. Did I get right your demand? By the way, could you approuve my answer if you found it useful, please? :)